# Check direct connected circle and draw plot

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to:

1. Generate points on a grid, and place a circle of arbitrary radius at each.

   ```
   GridGraph[{3, 3}, 
     VertexShapeFunction -> ({Opacity@0.5, 
          RGBColor[0.51, 0.74, 0.94], Disk[#, RandomReal[{0, 1}]]} &)]
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]
2. Connect points whose circles overlap, and create the corresponding `Graph`.

Comment: I found it quite difficult to understand the question (until I evaluated your code). I edited the question and tried to make it clearer. Please verify that it still matches what you wanted to ask.

Comment: Thank you, yes it's correct questions. 
The circles represent power transmission and i want check how topology are changes when power will degrees.

Answer (score 4):

```
g1 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[777]; vsizes = RandomReal[{0, .75}, 9]; 
   GridGraph[{3, 3}, ImagePadding -> 10, ImageSize -> 300, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
    VertexShapeFunction -> {v_ :> ({Opacity@0.5, 
      RGBColor[0.51, 0.74, 0.94], Disk[#, vsizes[[v]]]} &)}]];
vertexradii = Cases[Show[g1][[1]], t_TagBox :> 
    Rule[ToExpression@StringDrop[t[[-1, -1]], 9], t[[1, -1, -1]]], Infinity];
g2 = SetProperty[EdgeDelete[g1, i_ <-> j_ /; Total[{i, j} /. vertexradii] < 1], 
   {VertexCoordinates -> Thread[VertexList[g1] -> GraphEmbedding[g1]]}];
g3 = RemoveProperty[g2, VertexShapeFunction];
Grid[{Style[#, 16] & /@ {"g1", "g2", "g3"}, {g1, g2, g3}}, Spacings -> 1, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

**Controlling disk radii using `Locator`s:**

```
{r, c} = {3, 5};
g1 = GridGraph[{r, c}];
vcoords = GraphEmbedding[g1]; 
Deploy @ DynamicModule[{pt = # + {.01, .01} & /@ vcoords, 
   vertexradius = Array[# -> Norm[{.01, .01}] &, VertexCount[g1]]}, 
  Graphics[{Point@vcoords, EdgeForm[], RGBColor[0.51, 0.74, 0.94], Opacity[.5],
    Dynamic@Table[With[{i = i}, {Disk[vcoords[[i]], vertexradius[[i, 2]]], 
        Locator[Dynamic[pt[[i]], (pt[[i]] = #; 
            vertexradius[[i, 2]] = Norm[# - vcoords[[i]]]) &], 
         Style["●", Blue, FontSize -> 10]]}], {i, VertexCount[g1]}], 
    Gray, Thick, 
    Dynamic[Line[vcoords[[#]]] & /@ Select[Tuples[Range[r c], {2}],
       Total[# /. vertexradius] >= Norm[vcoords[[#[[1]]]] - vcoords[[#[[2]]]]] &]]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, c + 1}, {0, r + 1}}, ImageSize -> 600]]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
gridPoints = Tuples[Range[5], {2}];

radii = RandomReal[1, Length[gridPoints]];

am = UnitStep[Outer[Plus, radii, radii] - DistanceMatrix[N@gridPoints]];
am = am - IdentityMatrix@Length[am];

AdjacencyGraph[am, VertexCoordinates -> gridPoints, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> {v_ :> ({Disk[#, radii[[v]]], {GrayLevel[0, 1], Point[#]}} &)},
 VertexStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0.51, 0.74, 0.94, 0.5], EdgeForm[None]],
 EdgeShapeFunction -> "Line", 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, GrayLevel[0, 1]]
]
```

This method is simple, but not very efficient, because it measures the distance of all point pairs.  A much faster, but slightly more complicated way would be to take an appropriate `GraphPower` of the grid graph according to the maximum disk radius, and only compute the distance of connected points in the result grid.  Something similar could also be done with `Nearest` to filter down the point pairs to those whose distance is less than twice the max radius.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Would it be possible to place the individual elements of a connected component in a graph into a shape like in `CommunityStructure`? I simply want to see the connected components within the shape of a community rather than showing the vertices within a component by using the same colors.